# ajax progress bar not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, updateprogress

I am trying to present a ajax progress bar when a delete button is clicked. This delete button will do things and will take time to process.. The delete button is within a repeater. The code is below:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upDatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" ID="UpdateProgress1" DynamicLayout="false" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="upDatePanel">                            
                <ProgressTemplate>                                
                <img id="Img1" runat="Server" src="~/Images/ajax-loader.gif" height="50" width="50"  alt=""/>                            
                 </ProgressTemplate>                     
                 </asp:UpdateProgress>

                    <asp:Repeater ID="rptWork" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptWork_ItemDataBound">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" OnClick="btnDelete_Click"  Text="Delete" runat="server" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                            <tr>

                                <td>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" OnClick="btnDelete_Click"  Text="Delete" runat="server"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            </table>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I have put in a Thread.Sleep behind the delete button so when user clicks the progress bar appears however the process time takes abit longer. How can i make the progress bar stay on screen until the process is fully complete?

Comment: Have you tried moving the UpdateProgress panel to outside of the UpdatePanel?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the UpdateMode="Always" to see if your getting page updates.

If you use conditional you will have to call Update yourself on the panel (not sure if your doing this??)